# Approximate Simplify (or factorization)

Tags: algebraic-manipulation, approximation, factorization

Suppose I have

$$(2+2a+a^2)(RC)^2 + RC(5+2a)t+t^2$$

I can factor $(2+2a+a^2) = 1+(1+a)^2$. When I assume $a \gg 1$ then $1+(1+a)^2\approx (1+a)^2$. Then I can write:

$$(a+1)^2(RC)^2 + 2RC(5/2+a)t+t^2$$

Again, for large $a \gg 1$ I have $(5/2+a)\approx (1+a)$ and I can factor this expression into:

$$ ((a+1)RC + t)^2 $$

I call this *approximate* factorization if I take certain assumptions. As part of a larger expression, this term now cancels with another term.

Is there anything in Mathematica than can help with problems like this?

---

This is just a simple example. In my actual problem I have a large algebraic term where I am confident that I can simplify it under certain assumptions. However, this term is so large that I cannot do it by hand any more:

$$
\mathrm{MyTerm} = \frac{N}{D} \\
N = \left(a_1^2 R+a_1 R_o (4 B C R_o+1)+4 B C R_o^2\right)^2 \left(2 a_1^5 B C R^2+a_1^4 (4 B C R (R+R_o)+R)+a_1^3 (R+R_o) (4 B C (R+R_o)+1)+a_1^2 R_o \left(16 B^2 C^2 R R_o+8 B C (R+R_o)+1\right)+8 a_1 B C R_o^2 (2 B C (R+R_o)+1)+16 B^2 C^2 R_o^3\right) \\
D = (a_1+1) (a_1 R+R_o)^3 \left(4 a_1^2 B C R+4 a_1 B C (R+R_o)+a_1+4 B C R_o\right)^3
$$

Comment: Please show your code, so someone can help!

Comment: My question does not have code it is a conceptual question. "MyTerm" is the output of a larger Mathematica code (after `Simplify`). So far I tried to simplify it on paper. My question if there is a concept in Mathematica that can help with problems like that (I do not know what it could be).

Comment: Questions are expected to have code so that one can replicate issues and/or experiment with possible changes. Absent that, they generally fall outside the scope of the forum.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your first example  the following code

```
(Series[(2 + 2 a + a^2) (R C)^2 + R C (5 + 2 a) t + t^2 /. 
    a -> 1/A, {A, 0, -1}]^(1/2) // PowerExpand // Normal)^2 /. 
    A -> 1/a // FullSimplify
```

returns

```
((1 + a) C R + t)^2
```

as you wanted. You can also use expansion around infinity if you are familiar with it. Try

```
(Series[(2 + 2 a + a^2) (R C)^2 + R C (5 + 2 a) t + t^2,
  {a, Infinity, -1}]^(1/2) // Normal)^2 // Simplify
```

with same results. It takes some experimentation. The general method of power series is one way to do something like this. For more complicated exmples it requires many manual steps. The advantage is that arithmetic errors are reduced. It seems like a hard problem in general.

The general idea is similar to that of [Dual numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_number) where $e^2 = 0.$ Thus $(x + e)^2 = x^2 + 2 x e\ $ and so on.
In our case we wanted the variable $\ a \ $ to be large relative to all the other variables. We can do this by using $\ A := 1/a\ $ and then letting $\ A^2 = 0.\ $
This is where power series in $\ A\ $ come in. For example, take a polynomial in variable $\ a\ $
 $$ a^2 + b a + c = a^2(1 + \frac{b}{a} + \frac{c}{a^2}) = a^2(1 + b A + c A^2) = a^2(1 + b A +O(A^2)) \approx a^2 + ba.$$

This seems like an overly complicated method and it is. I don't know of a better one but I am sure Mathematica is capable enough to do something close. This only takes care of a single variable larger than all the others. You can even attempt multiscale analysis and computations but it will be much harder to keep track of the size order of the variables. My best advice to you is to determine the relative importance as far as size of your variables and expressions.

Comment: Thank you this looks like a good start! Didn't think of that. Can you elaborate why you expand over 1/a instead of a ? I agree that this seems like a hard problem and I do not expect it to be solved in general. Can you think of a way to apply this method when multiple variables exist? For example in my "MyTerm" case how would I decide over which variables (or combinations thereof) to expand?

Comment: Why not just expand around Infinity instead?

Comment: @CarlWoll Okay thanks! I just added that. Some people would prefer expanding in $z$ rather than $1/z$.

Comment: I still do not understand why you do the square root followed by squaring again (and this seems only required for expansion around A and not for infinity). Could you add a quick remark on that?

Comment: @divB Well, if you don't, then you get a slightly different expression. They are both approximate but there are many approximations possible.